# Is it necessary to have the knowledge of using terminal/command-prompt for learning python

Tags: python, windows, command-prompt

I saw a couple of tutorials and they all make use of termial/command-prompt and I just dont know how they work. Is it necessary to know how they work before learning python or you can just earn it like you would learn some other language(lets say C)

It'll be great if you could recommend something. 
NOTE: I am a windows user.

Comment: It's not *necessary* to learn Python but every programmer should have atleast rudimentary command line skills.

Answer (score 1):

Python can generally be used in two ways: interactively (command line) or by writing and executing modules (which are generally executed at the command line anyway). It is really hard to say if you *need* to have knowledge of the command line because it depends on your application.

Most of the power of Python comes from the fact that it is interactive. This means that you can write code at Python's command line to rapidly debug and develop larger programs. Some very powerful (open source) applications exist for programming in Python interactively ([IPython](http://ipython.org/), [PyLab](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/), [IDLE](http://docs.python.org/library/idle.html), etc.).

Windows also has some great IDEs (non-command line) for programming Python (Spyder, SciTE, etc.). Check out [PythonXY](http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/) or [Enthought](http://www.enthought.com/). You can download one installer that will install all these tools (both command line and IDE) and tons of modules.

So in short, no it is not necessary to have knowledge of terminal/command-prompt, especially for learning Python. However, once you begin to move beginner to intermediate, you will find that you will unlock Python's try potential when programming at the command line. Further, it is really not that hard to run Python at the command line. If you are writing code as scripts (modules), you can essentially do the same at the command line.

Answer (score 0):

No.  If you know how to open the command prompt, navigate to a directory ("cd") and list a directory ("dir" on windows and "ls" on linux), then you can probably jump right into those python tutorials.